# azure consumption API for past period

Tags: azure

i am using [MSFT API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/usage-details/list) to get usage details.

API is working fine, but issue with API is that it doesn't provide option to get similar details for past period (month/year etc.).

any way I can get past month details using this API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the answer, way to get past period record is =>

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingPeriods/202110/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails?api-version=2021-10-01
```

in above e.g.  **XXXXXXXXXXXX** is a subscription-id, and **202110** is period-id.